# Formula in Excel - Logarithmic Average

Tags: c#, excel, math, excel-formula, formula

I need to implement this equation:

[image: Logarithmic Sum]

In c# it is pretty straightforward:

```
static double LogarithmicSummed(IReadOnlyList<double> values)
{
    double outVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        outVal = outVal + Math.Pow(10, values[i] / 10);
    }
    return 10 * Math.Log10(outVal);
}
```

I need to verify the data in an excel sheet where I print out the data programmatically. That is the raw data, my c# calculations on the raw data AND the excel formual that should match my c# calculations. I just do not know how to write the formula in excel.

I know the rows and columns where the data are and they are next to each other. So for example, if I needed the arithmetic average, ie:

[image: Arithmetic average]

I could print out for each row:

```
// If row = 1, startColumn = A, endColumn = D, noOfColumn = 4. This would print: =SUM(A1:D1)/4
mean[row] = @"=SUM(" + startColumn + row + ":" + endColumn + row + ")/" + noOfColumns;
```

What would I print out to match the first formula I wrote? Or what would I need to write in Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without VBA:

Put your data in **A1** through **A10** and in **B1** enter:

```
=10^(A1/10)
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=10*LOG10(SUM(B1:B10))
```

[image]

You can avoid the "helper" column *(column **B**)* by using:

```
=10*LOG10(SUMPRODUCT(10^((A1:A10)/10)))
```

Comment: The thing it that I have multiple rows and columns of values, so if I have to make an intermediate calculation for each cell, it will get very messy and hard to get an overview. Your formula "without the helper column" gives wrong result.

Comment: @Daltons  Update your original question with a small sample of data and expected results and we can resolve the issue!

Comment: Sorry, it does work. I made a parentheses mistake. You understood the question perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If that's how you enter your formulas, then why not use the literal form of the sum? Ie use a `for` loop over the columns and fill in:

```
10*log(10^(A1/10)+10^(A2/10)+10^(A3/10)+10^(A4/10))
```